# Google Chrome extensions events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Can anyone tell me for chrome extensions how is possible for me to know if a new tab is created or modify. 
I tried using Content Scripts but i dont realy know how it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the chrome.tabs* API

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onCreated

There is an onCreate method that is fired when new tabs are created :)